# Mobile website - how to switch to desktop version

Tags: php, mobile, wordpress, mobile-website

I have a WordPress website ([abetterworldbydesign.com](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/)) which has user-agent detection to redirect mobile websites to a subdirectory. It is using the plugin: [WPtap Mobile Detector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptap-mobile-detector/)

I want to include a toggle link to switch between the mobile and desktop version. How can I make the site remember that a mobile user has switched to the desktop version and avoid redirecting that user to the mobile version again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session will probably be the easiest, or still detect mobile, but have a `?mobile=false` attached the URL that prevents the user from being redirected, but allows them to easily get back to the mobile site.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the HTTP_REFERRER is the easiest method - no cookies & just one check. 
If the referrer is on your domain - then don't redirect.